# Should you rather define several or only one input parameter (with all values) for child components

Tags: html, angular, components

I am faced with the question of how I should set up my Angular components with regard to inputs.

The first variant would be to create an input variable for each given value. This means that you would have to enter each variable individually when calling it:

[image]

The second variant would be to pack all the required values ​​in a model and only include this model. So in the end only one input:

[image]

Now I don't know which of the two variants is better suited for a large app with many components.

Is there one i should prefer from these two or are there more i dont know yet?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your component info what info you are passing for example if the component is a shared button in which expected inputs could be button name, class, status etc.

In that scenario instead of passing all inputs separately you could go with one object lets say `props` which contains button properties.

```
export interface IButtonProps {
 text: string;
 class: string;
 disabled?: boolean;
}

buttonData: IButtonProps;

this.buttonData = {
  ...this.buttonData,
  text: 'Submit',
  class: 'primary',
  disabled: false
}
```

In template instead of passing individual input pass an object of `buttonData`

```
<my-button [props]="buttonData"></my-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't really explain itself too well but here goes:

If your input's are all of the same type and used for the same thing, theres nothing wrong with putting all of them in an array and passing them to the child.

Instead of:

`[input]="'string1'" [input2]="'string2'"` you could do `[input]="['string1', 'string2']"`

However consider this:

```
[iconClass]="'my-icon-class'" [buttonClass]="'my-button-class'"
```

Each of the inputs do something completely different, so putting them inside of an array would be very bad practice.

What you could also do is put all inputs in an `object`, for example:

```
input = { iconClass: 'my-icon-class', buttonClass: 'my-button-class' };
[input]="input"
```

You should only be using this, if the inputs are somehow related or/and do the same thing / modify the same element in the child.